# Plot pandas df into boxplot & histogram

Tags: python, pandas, plot, histogram, boxplot

Currently I am trying to plot a boxplot into a histogram (without using seaborn). I have tried many varieties but I always get skewed graphs.

This was my starting point:

```
#Histogram
df.hist(column="Q7", bins=20, figsize=(14,6))

#Boxplot
df.boxplot(column="Q7",vert=False,figsize=(14,6))
```

which resulted in the following graph:

[image]

As you can see the boxplot and outliers are at the bottom, but I want it to be on top.

Anyone an idea?

Answer (score 0):

You can use subplots and set the percentage of the plot to ensure that the boxplot is first and the hist plot is below. In below example, I am using 30% for boxplot and 70% for bistogram. Also adjusted the spacing between the plots and used a common x-axis using sharex. Hope this is what you are looking for...

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(2, figsize=(14, 6), sharex=True, # Common x-axis
                       gridspec_kw={"height_ratios": (.3, .7)})  # boxplot 30% of the vertical space

#Boxplot
df.boxplot(column="Q7",vert=False,figsize=(14,6), ax=ax[0])
#Histogram
df.hist(column="Q7", bins=20, figsize=(14,6), ax=ax[1])
ax[1].title.set_size(0)
plt.subplots_adjust(hspace=0.1) ##Adjust gap between the two plots
```

[image]